# How can I validate a model attribute against another model attribute in Sails?

Tags: sails.js

Let's say I have an `Invoice` model in SailsJS. It has 2 date attributes: `issuedAt` and `dueAt`. How can I create a custom validation rule that check that the due date is equal or greater than the issued date?

I tried creating a custom rule, but it seems I cannot access other properties inside a rule.

```
module.exports = {

  schema: true,

  types: {
    duedate: function(dueAt) {
      return dueAt >= this.issuedAt // Doesn't work, "this" refers to the function, not the model instance
    }
  },

  attributes: {

    issuedAt: {
      type: 'date'
    },

    dueAt: {
      type: 'date',
      duedate: true
    }

  }

};
```

Comment: Does not seem possible to me, calling rule https://github.com/balderdashy/anchor/blob/master/lib/match.js#L203 is not bound to a function. Enforce your contract manually (or on the database)

Answer (score 3):

I hope you found a solution now, but for those interested to a good way to handle this i will explain my way to do it.

Unfortunatly as you said you can't access others record attributes in attribute customs validation function.

@Paweł Wszoła give you the right direction and here is a complete solution working for Sails@1.0.2 :

```
// Get buildUsageError to construct waterline usage error
const buildUsageError = require('waterline/lib/waterline/utils/query/private/build-usage-error');

module.exports = {

  schema: true,

  attributes: {

    issuedAt: {
      type: 'ref',
      columnType: 'timestamp'
    },

    dueAt: {
      type: 'ref',
      columnType: 'timestamp'
    }

  },

  beforeCreate: (record, next) => {
    // This function is called before record creation so if callback method "next" is called with an attribute the creation will be canceled and the error will be returned 
    if(record.dueAt >= record.issuedAt){
      return next(buildUsageError('E_INVALID_NEW_RECORD', 'issuedAt date must be equal or greater than dueAt date', 'invoice'))
    }
    next();
  }

};
```

Answer (score 2):

beforeCreate method in model as first param takes values. The best place for this kind of validation I see here.

```
beforeCreate: (values, next){
  if (values.dueAt >= values.issuedAt) {
      return next({error: ['...']})
  }
  next()
}
```

Comment: Hello, does this code prevent the model from being created? Meaning, is Waterline looking at the parameter of next to check if it's an error object, and in this case stops the cretion process?